# Rewrite Rule add query string parameter as Subdomain to URL in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to integrate google signin in my application.I have dynamic subdomains.As I came to know wildcards are not supported in Oath signin.Therefore I am sending state parameter while signin and in that state parameter i am passing domain name and in developer console i have origin and redirect as **https://mydomain.zingapps.com**.I am having **mydomain** as main subdomain.

Now I am able to signin successfully.But while redirecting i am getting URL as

https://mydomain.myapps.com/?state=testdomain&code=16
     digit code

**But i want url to be like this**

```
    https://testdomain.myapps.com/account
```

Here I want the state parameter to be my subdomain after redirecting.

In htaccess I am doing like this.I know its wrong.I dont have that much idea how to do it.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myapps\.
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} state=([a-z0-9]+)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.mydomain.com/$1 [L]
```

Can anyone tell how to achieve this?

Comment: Anything after `#` is not called query string and is not even sent to web server. It needs to be done on client side only e.g. via Javascript.

Comment: Can you explain a bit please.I am sending state parameter along with client id,redirect_uri,scope while doing signin.

Comment: See; https://www.google.com/search?q=url+fragment+example

Comment: I have updated my question.I am getting as question mark now not #

Comment: Word `account` is not in original URL so that should be added as a static text?

Comment: Yeah it should be added as a static text to the url.Because i have that url configured in routes.js.I just want to add state parameter as subdomain and account text at the end like this. https://testdomain.zingyapps.com/account.This should be my return url.The state parameter will be dynamic.Its not static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this rule as your top rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomaon\.zingyapps\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)state=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://%1.zingyapps.com/account?#!/sales [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: As I suggested before part of URL after `#` doesn't even reach web server hence `RewriteRule` cannot remove it. That is all happening via Javascript only

Comment: yeah but i have removed the #.It was coming as query string.Ok if it is not possible to remove # can i add #!/sales in front of it?

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.I will try this :)